# showMessageDialog pops up even with valid search -- Java

Tags: java, search, jdialog

```
private void searchButtonActionPerformed() {
    String tempTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter Movie Title:");
    if(tempTitle != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
            ProductDataExtended tempProd = product[i];
            if(tempTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(tempProd.getMovieName())) {
                INDEX = i;
                Products();
                break;
            }//End if 
            else if("".equals(tempTitle)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No movie title entered!"
                        , "Oops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                break;
            }//End else if
            else if(!tempTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(tempProd.getMovieName())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Product not found.");
                break;
            }//End else
        }//End for loop
    }//End if
}//End method
```

My problem is that in this part here,

```
else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product not found.");
                    }
```

the message dialog still pops up even when a valid search is entered.  Any ideas on why, or how I can fix this?

If I take this part out, the search function works perfectly; aside from the fact it doesn't display a message for invalid searches.

Comment: What do you mean by valid search?  Have you considered the possibility that the other cases weren't true, allowing execution to fall to the else block?

Comment: If I search for a product within my array one of two things happen:

if the else portion is present, it pops up regardless of if the product is there or not.

or two, if it's not present, the search function works as intended.  It just doesn't pop up any message for invalid searches.

Comment: In order to avoid that code from being executed,  one of three things must be true.  The search term is empty or the product array is empty or the search term matches every product title.  The last condition can not be satisfied if you have multiple product titles in your array.

Comment: @recursive Well, the array isn't empty, as I have 4 products in it and it works fine without the else portion.  If the search term is empty, that's handled by the second block "else if".  Basically the point of the final condition is anything other than the previous conditions should return the dialog.

Comment: The if block is inside the loop.  It's executing for all four products.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do was change

```
else if(!tempTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(tempProd.getMovieName())){}
```

to

```
else if(i == product.length - 1) {}
```

and presto!  It works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `tempTitle` is equal to the second element of `product` and not the first.

In the first traversal of the `for`-loop the first `if` is `false`, the second `if` is `false` and the third `if` is `true`, resulting in `"Product not found"`.
The loop won't be traversed a second time due to the `break`.

Only after comparing the `tempTitle` to all elements of `produkt` can you be sure that it's not present.